# UserDefined Comparison Operator (operator> , operator< etc)

Tags: c++

I'm new to Userdefined Comparison Operator. I was reading a book where the following example is mentioned :

```
struct P { 
           int x, y;
           bool operator<(const P &p) { 
                 if (x != p.x)
                   return x < p.x;
                 else 
                   return y < p.y; } 
         };
```

I want to understand `bool operator<(const P &p)`.
Particularly i understand that `bool` is the return type of the operator i.e. return value is either `true` or `false`.

But I am confused , what is the significance of **<** in `operator<` and how does this operator is actually working? What values are being compared?

Comment: `*this` is compared with `p`. The purpose of this code is so that someone can have two `P` variables (let's call them `a` and `b`) and write `a < b` to compare those variables

Comment: Side note - conditions are usually cleaner, and have another chance of being implemented, if you compare for equality (==) than inequality (!=).

Comment: Side-note: In C++11, it's often nicer to delegate comparison work to `std::tuple` [via `std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), as it avoids the verbosity and error-prone nature of hand-implementing lexicographic (element by element) comparisons. Implementing the function as `return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(p.x, p.y);` reduces the amount of custom code, makes the rules of comparison more obvious for the simple cases, and (since `std::tie` is reference based, and therefore copy-free) it's unlikely to add any overhead.

Comment: Note that should actually be `bool operator<(const P &p) const {...}`, or it will eventually surprise you.

Answer (score 1):

```
P a, b;
bool ret = a < b;
```

It actually is:

```
P a, b;
bool ret = a.operator<(b);  // And < in operator<:  x.operator<(p.x)
```

Did this help you to a better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a struct with two integers. X and Y. What the code above is saying is if X in the struct you're in (also known as "this") is not equal to the x in the struct passed in (p) then do a regular less than comparison between x and p's x. If they are equal, then compare the y of this to p's y.

The significance of "<" in "operator<" is to let the compiler know you're overloading the "<" operator allowing you to use it to compare to structs of type P. If you don't overload the < operator for a custom type you cannot use it to compare two of those objects.

Comment: but what would be the difference between  operator> and operator< ? how will it effect the above code?